# Array: make object property into array key

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like so:

```
arr[0] = {name: 'name1', attribute1: 'a1Value1', attribute2: 'a2Value1'} 
arr[1] = {name: 'name2', attribute1: 'a1Value2', attribute2: 'a2Value2'}
```

what I want to achive is to create second array with name attribute as array key so it looks like this:

```
   arr2[name1] = {attribute1: 'a1Value1', attribute2: 'a2Value1'}
   arr2[name2] = {attribute1: 'a1Value2', attribute2: 'a2Value2'}
```

Is there an easy and efficient way to do it with underscoreJS or plain JS?

Comment: You don't want _array_, you want **object**

Comment: That second method is an object, not an array.

Comment: `array.reduce` would probably do the trick. What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: Simply iterate over the array and add a new entry to the new object for every element...

Comment: Don't you just hate it when that happens? .. I mean seriously?  why not wait at least 60 min before **HOLD** or **CLOSE** .. darn... I was on a roll here, created some snazzy ninja kung-fu-style business and now I can't post it.  . t(-.-t)

Comment: @Tushar or maybe a Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this is what you want.

Here is jsbin link. http://jsbin.com/soheni/edit?html,js,console,output

```
var arry = [{name: 'name1', attribute1: 'a1Value1', attribute2: 'a2Value1'}, {name: 'name2', attribute1: 'a1Value2', attribute2: 'a2Value2'}];

function convert(arry){
  var data = {};
  arry.forEach(function(obj){
    var nameKey = obj.name;
    delete obj.name;
    data[nameKey] = obj;
  });
  return data;
}

console.log(convert(arry));
```

Output:

```
{
   name1:{
           attribute1: "a1Value1",
           attribute2: "a2Value1"
         },
   name2: {
           attribute1: "a1Value2",
           attribute2: "a2Value2"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty if you don't really care about the `name` property in the result:

```
var obj = arr.reduce(function(p,c) {
    p[c.name] = c;
    return p;
},{});
```

If you do want the `name` property removed, then you can `delete` it from `c`. However, this would be mutating the original value. If you want the original array still with the `name` property in tact, then you will need to copy the object instead (but without the `name` property).

So you could do:

```
var obj = arr.reduce(function(p,c) {
    p[c.name] = c;
    delete c.name;   // note this removes it from the original array too!
    return p;
},{});
```

Or:

```
var obj = arr.reduce(function(p,c) {
    var cheapCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(c));   // note this is not necessarily the most
                                                     // efficient way to clone an object
    delete cheapCopy.name;
    p[c.name] = cheapCopy;
    return p;
},{});
```

Personally, I would be inclined to just leave the `name` property there unless there's a really compelling reason (i.e. it actually causes a performance problem or some other piece of code will complain if it exists) to go to all the trouble of deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it...

```
var arr = [];
arr.length = 3;
arr[0] = { name: 'name1', attribute1: 'a1Value1', attribute2: 'a2Value1' };
arr[1] = { name: 'name2', attribute1: 'a1Value2', attribute2: 'a2Value2' };
arr[2] = { name: 'name3', attribute1: 'a1Value3', attribute2: 'a2Value3' };

var newObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var arrObj = arr[i];
    var propName = arrObj.name;
    delete arrObj.name;
    newObj[propName] = arrObj;
}

console.log('New Object:', newObj);
for (var key in newObj) {
    console.log('New Object By Key/Value:', key, newObj[key]);
}
```

Or, shorter...

```
var newObj = {};
arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    var propName = obj.name;
    delete obj.name;
    newObj[propName] = obj;
});
console.log('newObj:', newObj);
```

You may wish to copy the properties over manually or do a cloned copy of the original object, but I haven't done that here purely to simplify my example.